# Unable to redirect perforce output from stdout to a file/variable

Tags: linux, shell, perforce, io-redirection

I am writing a bash shell script in Ubuntu 10.4 Linux. It uses some `p4` commands. The problem is that all the output from the p4 commands is displayed on the terminal and does not get redirected even when using `>` or catching it in a variable.

Examples:

```
p4 files *.c > results.txt   // displays results on the screen and results.txt is empty
result=$(p4 files *.c)       // result is empty
```

Is there any flag in `p4` which can be used to get the task done or some other switch in Linux?

Comment: Your way seems to be OK. Anyways try `p4 files *.c 1>/fullpath/results.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: maybe it is writing to stderr. try `p4 files *.c > results.txt 2>&1`